Selenium opens different webpage than the one provided
I'm trying to scrape the results from this website:
https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/result.jsf?_vid=P12-M20EG6-49828
that is an advanced search from the original website.
This is my code:
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/result.jsf?_vid=P12-M20EG6-49828')

results_dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "resultsPerPage"))
)
results_dropdown.click()
results_option_200 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//option[@value='200']"))
)
results_option_200.click()

The driver opens chrome just fine, the problem is that the page opened is this one:
https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/search.jsf
that is not even the advanced search that I need.
I don't understand this behaviour, since other times I was able to open selenium directly on the url created by a manual advance search (on other website, not this one).
What I need is to perform the advance search from this website:
https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/advancedSearch.jsf
with the offices field marked as "Italy" and languages field with "Italian" as value, and then in the following page (that should be the one provided to selenium) to select 200 results per page and then to scrape until page 51, but for now it's ok to access at least the first page with the selected filters.

That URL returns a HTTP status code 302: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302 (i.e. it redirects you to another site).
